# Different output of parted and fdisk

Tags: fdisk, parted, table-partitioning

I have a strange CentOS behaviour,
When I type `parted -l` command on my server I got following results :

```
Model: DELL PERC H730P Adp (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 5758GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: pmbr_boot

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  3146kB  2097kB                        bios_grub
 2      3146kB  1077MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1077MB  5749GB  5748GB  ext4
 4      5749GB  5758GB  8590MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

And everything seems to be fine but when I check the same with `fdisk -l` I got :

```
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 79700B71-AB44-4ED5-95EC-0FE5E3C0CF1D


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048         6143      2M  BIOS boot       
 2         6144      2103295      1G  Microsoft basic 
 3      2103296  11229198335    5.2T  Microsoft basic 
 4  11229198336  11245975551      8G  Linux swap
```

As you can see types of filesystems are different in each cases and it bothers me a lot.
Who can explain me what causes such diverse in output results ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is, that parted shows the file system, and fdisk shows the partition type.

There is no discrepancy here.

- partition type: `Microsoft basic`
- filesytem: `ext4`

`Microsoft basic` is technically not the correct type for a Linux partition, there is `Linux filesystem` for that, but practically that doesn't really make a difference.